# How to make the size fixed of sqlite DB or local DB in android..?

Tags: android, database, memory, android-sqlite

I am working android native app, in my app i need to make the local db size fixed nearer to 5MB, If the db size is full more than or equal to 5MB. I am going to remove some data from it.

So, how to make size fixed  of DB, i am using SQLite DB in android. Do anybody have sample code or knowledge of it.

I have done some google but don't get the proper answer of it. So,any help will be appreciated and helpful to me..

Thanx

Comment: anybody have simple code of what? What have you tried so far???

Comment: Do you store images in your db? or any other BLOB object?

Comment: Try getting your database file size with 
`getDatabasePath("your_db_file_name.db").length();` and make the necessary changes if it's size is near 5MB